# Configure NGINX to wrap non-SSL services with SSL

Tags: sockets, ssl, nginx

We have a webserver and a number of node services running side-by-side with the webserver. The services all use sockets and the webserver also has a socket which the browser then communicates with all this using the reverse-proxy aspects of NGINX.

Now, we want to set up NGINX so that it can handle the incoming SSL (port 443) requests, but the webserver and the sockets to remain on port 80 (http/ws), basically wrapping out configuration securely.

We have installed certificates (self-signed at this time), and I can get the webserver aspect of it working, but all of the socket communications get errors.

```
2019/03/14 10:27:31 [error] 14279#14279: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ::1, server: _, request: "GET /web_app_socket/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mbz1xMB HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:3001/web/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mbz1xMB", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/"
```

And on client-side, I get this:

```
GET https://localhost/liveview/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mbz1vtE 502
```

This is what I have in the `default` configuration file for NGINX for the webserver socket:

```
    location /web_app_socket/ { ### route the websockets of the web app
        #Configure proxy to pass data to upstream service
        proxy_pass http://web_app/web/socket.io/;
        #HTTP version 1.1 is needed for sockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    }
```

I have tried so many configuratons that I am getting lost in what is supposed to be the proper way to do this (or, can NGINX do this?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fixed this. I just removed `proxy_redirect off;` and it worked.

Now, it looks like this:

```
    location /web_app_socket/ { ### route the websockets of the web app
        #Configure proxy to pass data to upstream service
        proxy_pass http://web_app/web/socket.io/;
        #HTTP version 1.1 is needed for sockets
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_read_timeout 600s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    }
```